# Is there a way to concatenate JS and CoffeeScript files using Harp server?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, harp

I would like to request /js/app.js from HarpJS server and have it preprocess a folder of coffeescript and javascript. For example, say I have:

```
/js/module/a.js
/js/module/b.coffee
/js/module/c.coffee
/js/app.coffee
```

Is there a way to request `/js/app.js` such that the response contains the concatenation of `/js/module/a.js`, of `/js/module/b.js`. and `/js/module/c.js` responses?

Comment: Also this is an [open issue](https://github.com/sintaxi/harp/issues/127) on the Harp repo.

Comment: @Mathletics Your quip about Google searching is pretty rude.  The snippet you provide would concatenate on startup, which is not what I want.  In my question, had you read it, I specify that I want the server to respond to a request with the concatenated result.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude; I wanted to clarify what, if anything, you've tried to solve the problem yourself. I don't see anything in your question indicating that a static concatenation _would not_ solve your problem.

Comment: @Mathletics About 20% of the question is dedicated to describing ```Is there a way to request /js/app.js such that the response contains the concatenation of /js/module/a.js, of /js/module/b.js. and /js/module/c.js responses?```  Unfortunately, the solution you posted and then deleted would not solve that because every request would be the same set of scripts.  I'm attempting to use Harp for development purposes, so dynamic script compilation upon every request is a requirement.

Comment: I'd never heard of harp before this question; don't get mad at me for trying to help. In any case, looks like you're SOL as this exact issue has been open in their repo since Oct '13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up customizing the terraform module, writing a preprocessor called `man`.

Here is the diff from Harp:
https://github.com/sintaxi/terraform/compare/master...thesmart:master